# Remove string characters

Tags: r

I have a string

```
"Manager *?position (is not *# filled"
```

I need this

```
"Manager position is not filled"
```

I tried:

```
 paste(strsplit(st, "[*?(#]")[[1]],collapse="")
```

But, the spacings are not correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use `strsplit()`, I think this way should get the spacing right.

```
> st <- "Manager *?position (is not *# filled"
> ss <- strsplit(st, "[[:punct:]]|\\s")[[1]]
> paste(ss[nzchar(ss)], collapse = " ")
# [1] "Manager position is not filled"
```

Comment: I like the `nzchar` function.  I guess if you use:  paste(strsplit(st, "[[:punct:] ]+")[[1]], collapse=" ")
[1] "Manager position is not filled", could avoid `nzchar`

Comment: not sure why would someone prefer to use 3 different functions instead of just one `gsub`....

Comment: @David.  Yes, `gsub` code is shorter, but `Richard` answered how to correct my code

Comment: @will , in place of `nzchar`, you could also just do `ss[ss != ""]`.  They turn out the same for this problem.

Comment: @Richard. Thanks. I like `clean` from `Tyler's` post. clean(paste(ss, collapse=" "))

Comment: @will your code was wrong. We showed you the correct way. There is no need to run 3 different functions when there is built in, vectorized and fully optimized function for this in R. You could as well calculate sum with a `for` loop and so on

Answer (score 0):

Could Try

```
gsub("[[:punct:] ]+"," ", st)
```

Or

```
gsub("[*?(#]", "", st)
```

Although the latter will return an extra space

Comment: You can modify it to:  gsub("[[:punct:] ]+"," ", st)
[1] "Manager position is not filled" for the extra space.

Comment: Good idea @arkun, modified

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use the package `stringr` and the spaces are taken care of:

```
string  <- "Manager *?position (is not *# filled"
str_replace_all(string = string, pattern = "[[:punct:]]+", replacement = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using qdap:

```
st <- "Manager *?position (is not *# filled"

library(qdap)
clean(strip(st, lower.case = FALSE))

## [1] "Manager position is not filled"
```

`strip` removes the special characters and `clean` removes the extra spaces.